# Type conversion for function parameters

Tags: c++, reference, initialization

```
class A{
};

class B{
public:
    B();
    B(const &A);
};

void foo(A &a){

}

int main(){
   B b;
   foo(b); //error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘A&’ from expression of type ‘B’
   return 0;
}
```

In the above code, I have a compilation error

**error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘A&’ from expression of type ‘B’**

The error can be solved by function overloading of foo(). However,do you have any other suggestion how I can solve the problem?

function foo(A &a) does not use parameter "a" as input. parameter "a" is simply the output of the function foo(A &a).

thanks.

Comment: the "error" is that your code doesn't make sense. It's not clear what you want the code to be doing, and then it's pretty hard to tell you how you should fix it. You could just comment out the function call too, which would "solve" it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many options... hard to know what to recommend without understanding what you're program is attempting.  The little insight we're given into the logical relationship between A and B is:

- only one of B's constructor's requires a non-const reference to an A object
- foo() is intended to work with either A or B

this implies a pointer to A may be being saved in B, but begs the question: should foo() work with all B's (perhaps using a default-constructed A if none was provided at construction) or only those that were constructed with reference to an A?

Design options include:

- derive B from A (but your default constructor suggests a B can exist without having been "tied" to an A)
- add `A& get_A()` and/or `const A& get_A() const` member(s) to `class B`, then call `foo(b.get_A());`

  - do this implicitly with `operator A&()` and `operator const A&() const`
  - you may prefer `A* get_A()` et al if A is optional
- `template <class A_or_B> foo(A_or_B&)` if A and B provide the right members/semantics for foo to work on either
- overload foo, providing different implementations for each type

Exploratory code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    int n_;
};

void foo(A& a)
{
   a.n_++;
}


struct B
{
    // e.g. B() : p_a_(new A), owner_(true) { } ?
    //      ~B() { if (owner_) delete p_a_; }
    B(A& a) : p_a_(&a) { }

    operator A&() { return *p_a_; }

    A* p_a_;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.n_ = 2;
    B b(a);
    foo(a);
    foo(b);
    std::cout << a.n_ << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Note that the implicit conversion will only work if the function/method takes an object or a const-reference as parameter.

Comment: thank you for the solutions. I forgot to say that function foo(A &a) does not use parameter "a" as input. parameter "a" is simply the output of the function foo(A &a).

Comment: @Space_COwbOy: it can't be a temporary, but can return a reference to a variable stored in B, or for which a pointer is available.  @iampat: you're welcome.  If foo(A& a) is loading "a", then again any of these approaches are valid.  Some sample code added above.

Comment: @iampat: In that case your only alternatives are inheritance and overloading. Or consider not using output-parameters, but return values instead.

Comment: @iampat: You are right. It's too early, I should stop posting right now and drink another coffee first...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to implicitly convert an object B to an object A. Considering that these are to separate classes, the compiler won't be able to do this. Whilst it is possible to explicitly cast a pointer or reference to object B to a */& of object A, this would confuse the compiler and is a really bad idea.

It is like you are asking the compiler to convert an apple to an orange, can't be done. If B was a subclass of A, this would be totally possible. But you cannot simply do this as a work around if the two classes have nothing or little in common. If they do however, and you have several related classes, create a base class (that contains shared methods), and make all these classes derive from it.

And again, please don't do something like `(A*)(&b)` because this will lead to run-time issues if you don't know what class you are actually getting in foo()'s parameter (again, unless B derives from A).

Of course, the best course of action is to overload Foo().

EDIT: You see, you can convert from A to B in B's constructor. But you need an A and have a B, so the REVERSE conversion is needed. This is why your current code will not work.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I forgot to say that function foo(A &a) does not use parameter "a" as input. parameter "a" is simply the output of the function foo(A &a)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really want A and B as unrelated classes? If A and B class share *is-a* relationship then better you derive B from A.

```
class B : public A
```

then also `foo(b)` with foo(A& a) as signature will result into object slicing.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way.. if you are willing to assign the object B in the object A. You need to see the relationship whether they compatable or not.

To make compile from my perpective try below:

```
class A{ 

}; 

class B: public A{ 
public: 
    B(){
    }
    B(const A&){
    }
}; 

void foo(A &a){ 

}
```

Hope it worths.